# Using ARM Cortex on breadboard

Tags: embedded, arm, breadboard, cortex-m4

I want to know if can I use an [ARM-Cortex-M4](https://www.arm.com/products/silicon-ip-cpu/cortex-m/cortex-m4) processor directly on a breadboard and then create a microcontroller on a breadboard. I already tried searching google but didn't find anything.

Please note that I am taking about "creating" a microcontroller on a breadboard and NOT "using" a microcontroller on a breadboard.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you have an IC manufacturing plant if you want to make processors? What are your definitions for a processor and microcontroller?

Comment: @Justme, For example if you go to this [development board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f429idiscovery.html)  and then if you see in "All features" it is using [STM32F429ZIT6 microcontroller](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/STM32F429ZIT6?qs=DqCdCwOw4%2F5LWpMGYjTR8w%3D%3D)  and so if you then go to the details on this microcontroller it finally says it is using ARM cortexM4.
So I want to achieve say whatever STM32F429ZIT6 microcontroller has done using ARM cortex on a breadboard.

Comment: I'm not aware of stand-alone AMR Cortex-M4 processors (unless it's an FPGA IP core). Can you link the exact processor IC you're talking about.

Comment: What you link to on Arm's site is not a physical product. Arm doesn't sell chips, they sell designs that chip manufacturers (ST and many others) use to make chips.

Comment: Maybe at this point it would be useful to google "die pictures" of various electronic parts, just to learn how complex something like a voltage regulator is. And a MCU is thousand times more complex yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a couple of things here. Arm themselves sell Microprocessor core *architectures* and *core layouts for putting in an IC*. You need to have access to a chip factory and extensive tooling to take one of these cores, and make a microcontroller out of it.

Breadboard doesn't come into play anywhere there. You need to do this on a chip wafer. You can't even buy such a core implemented on an IC – it would be useless, because you *need* to add things like power distribution, RAM, and internal buses to it before it can function as a component.

It's physically impossible to even route enough signals for the buses internal to such a microcontroller on a breadboard. Also, breadboard has very bad electrical properties, so that this wouldn't work for a host of other problems, starting with the fact that you need to add strong drivers to your chip in order to even be able to drive the capacitive load a breadboard line is.

Comment: Can you please provide link to the "core layouts" , core layout is a physical thing or a specification?

Comment: it's what is typically called an *IP core*, i.e. a large file that tells a chip layout program how to add the physical implementation of that processor core to a chip layout containing all the other necessary things that make the core useful, so that it can be sent to a factory for production of the chip.

Comment: arm sells no physical chips.

Comment: @stng Take a look at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226820/what-exactly-does-arm-sell-to-vendors

Answer (score 2):

You can get ARM Cortex M4 on small boards that can be used on a breadboard, for example, the so-called "Black Pill", which are in a form factor similar to an Arduino Nano. There are many suppliers, the image below came from [here](https://universal-solder.ca/product/stm32-black-pill-v3-stm32f411ceu6/) but shop around if you want to buy some. This type uses an STM32F411 which has a Cortex M4 core.

[image]

From what I've seen, programming via STLINK  (a separate module and those 4 pins off to the left) is more reliable than the bootloader, mostly because they've picked too high a crystal clock frequency for the RC clocked program in the bootloader to be able to guess the precise crystal frequency being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing things up here. ARM-Cortex M4 is the CPU core type (basically the language the CPU talks), STM32F429ZIT6 the actual microcontroller you can buy. There are other microcontrollers with the same CPU Core, but maybe different amount of memory or pin layout.

As I can tell, none of these can be used on a breadboard, because they have the wrong format and far to many pins. Without additional components (such as a specific PCB) only DIL-shaped ICs can be used on a breadboard. ARM CPUs are much to complex for that, they have 100 or more pins and would be huge.

There are other microcontrollers that are available in DIL-shapes, e.g. the Arduino Uno CPU, but that one is of course much weaker than an ARM cortex M4.

Answer (score 0):

There does not exist physical CPUs that only contain an ARM Cortex-M4 core with no peripherals. You always get them integrated with peripherals so you have an MCU.